# Disable a winform button based on selected in list box

Tags: c#, winforms

I haven't found a search friendly way to ask this, though I'm sure the answer is easy.  I want to disable a button if there is nothing selected in a list box (index is -1). Using the IndexChanged event kinda works, unless you change something else on the form.  The index changes to -1, but the event doesn't fire.  Is there an event that fires when anything on the form changes and I can check my state then?

Sorry for being too brief... I was posting from my phone.

Here's what I thought should work.

```
private void SourceFolderListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetDeleteFolderButtonStatus();
    }

private void SetDeleteFolderButtonStatus()
    {
        if (SourceFolderListBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
            DeleteFromSourceButton.Enabled = false;
        else DeleteFromSourceButton.Enabled = true;
    }

private void SourceFolderListBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetDeleteFolderButtonStatus();
    }
```

So the bug is if I edit a different field on the form, the selection in `SourceFolderListBox` clears (index changes to -1) but the button stays enabled.

My workaround is to call `SetDeleteFolderButtonStatus()` every time I change something.  That feels sloppy to me, but I am relatively new.

Comment: Maybe also subscribe to the `Leave` or `LostFocus` event to detect when "you change something else on the form"?

Comment: *unless you change something else on the form. The index changes to -1* → Could you please share a [MCVE]?

Comment: Hello, It would be great if you share what have done already

Comment: @Sweeper I don't see an event for `LostFocus`, would it be the same as `Leave`?

Comment: The [MCVE] should reproduce this behavior: → if I edit a different field on the form, the selection in SourceFolderListBox clears (index changes to -1)*

Comment: @RezaAghaei I'm sorry but I'm unclear on what your asking.  I am using debugging to watch the state of the index, as well as visually the ListBox selection clears. 
 Thanks for your patience, this is my first post.

Comment: @DougCosh In fact the behavior which you are talking about *"change something else on the form. The index changes to -1"* is not something standard. We need to know how to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: @RezaAghaei  I see.  What I am referring to is clicking an unrelated button, or changing text in an unrelated text box, _then_ the index of ListBox changes to -1.

Comment: When there is something selected in the `ListBox`, clicking on another *unrelated* control will not change selected index of list box automatically, unless you have written some code or have done some settings to do that. To be able to help you to solve the problem, you (then we) should be able to reproduce the problem. I strongly recommend you reading about [MCVE]. At the first step, it will help you to find/solve the problem in a clean environment. Then if you couldn't solve it yourself, it helps us to reproduce the problem and solve the same problem.

Comment: @RezaAghaei  Thanks for the advice.  I think I better understand what you need.  I will write an independent program that does nothing but this and see what I get.

Comment: It's bad design to disable UI controls, the user has no idea what the problem is, it would be better to allow the button to work and display a message to the user why they can't proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it was me confusing me.  I haven't figured out Bindings yet, so I had written my own method to refresh my data on every data point.  I was calling this method every time a field changed, which reset the index in the problem ListBox.

Thanks to @RezaAghaei For helping me learn to fix my own mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Me thinks that there are 2 solutions here:

1) Click on button and select properties -> search option [Enabled] -> Change from true to false.

2) Or just write that code: `button.Enabled = false;`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include code the first time.  I've edited my question now and you'll see that's the method I'm using to control the button.